# I can't get Classes to work right in any shape or form

Tags: python-2.7

Sorry to bother you guys with something like this, but new at this.  Having a horrible time getting Classes to produce any output.  Tried this in 3 IDE's and it comes up with no output.  It could be I'm not including a library or my IDE's aren't set up right. Here's my simple program.

```
class Hello:
         def printHello(self):
         print ("hello")

 x = Hello()
 x.printHello()
```

Comment: Perhaps indent the code correctly? This won't run at all.

Comment: Try to use the same indentation from the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper indentation in Python is mandatory in order to define blocks of code.
In your case you should have

```
class Hello:                   #line 1
         def printHello(self): #line 2
             print ("hello")   #line 3
                               #line 4
x = Hello()                    #line 5
x.printHello()                 #line 6
```

with no spaces before `x` in lines 5 and 6 and `print()` on line 3 should be indented as well because it is part of the `printHello()` function (just like the `def` is part of `class Hello`).

Comment: I'll look it over.  Thank u.